# Dynamically make the variable and get the corresponding value in shell script

Tags: bash, shell

I have written the shell script which gets the variables from other script(def.sh)

My def.sh looks like below:

```
SERVERS[0]=host1.com
SERVERS[1]=host1.com

SERVER1_HOME_DIR="/path1"
SERVER2_HOME_DIR="/path2"
```

My main.sh will try to use these variables from def.sh using for loop:

```
count=1
for server in ${SERVERS[@]}
do
echo "value " $(echo server${count}_HOME_DIR) // I'm not getting   the /path1 here
count=`expr $count + 1`
done
```

Hi,

It will still printing the value `SERVER1_HOME_DIR` & `SERVER2_HOME_DIR`

Please help to get the value of the server home directories.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can build the variable name and store it in a variable and use that.  When doing variable expansion in braces, if the first char is `!` the rest can be the name of the variable that will be expanded and be the name of the variable for the "outer" expansion.  Try it like so:

```
name=SERVER${count}_HOME_DIR
echo ${!name}
```

Comment: @developer Glad that worked. It might actually make more sense to use an array for the paths as well though, instead of trying to build a variable name on the fly